# Is it known which titans follow in power to the Founding Titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In the last episode of the anime, season 3 episode 6, it's stated that the Founding Titan is the most powerful of all titans. Is it known where all or any of the other titans are in the scale of power among them?

Comment: Afaik, if i remember correctly, the founding titan is superior to the others because of the co-ordinate, i.e. the power to control normal titans. The other transforming titans have different powers, each with their advantages and disadvantages. There is no objective ranking in the source material and hence any such would be purely subjective. Kind of like the strongest Straw hat...

Comment: @arcane actually it seems there is in an official guidebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is noted that the Founding Titan is the strongest one.

It isn't known in the manga/anime how the Titans are ranked, but statistics do exist for certain titans.

Colussus Titan Statistics spoilers below

> Power 11/10
>
> Speed 3/10
>
> Size 11/10
>
> Elusiveness 10/10
>
> Threat 10/10

Armored Titan Statistics spoilers below

> Power 8/10
>
> Speed 6/10
>
> Hardness 11/10
>
> Machoness 10/10
>
> Legend 10/10

Female Titan Statistics spoilers below

> Power 6/10
>
> Speed 8/10
>
> Hardness 10/10
>
> Combat 11/10
>
> Sexiness 10/10

Beast Titan Statistics spoilers below

> Power 7/10
>
> Speed 5/10
>
> Ruthless 8/10
>
> Smart 11/10
>
> Wildness 10/10

Comment: Where are these stats sourced from? They appear to be a fan-based rather than an official statistic

Comment: @Wondercricket These are from one of the official Guidebooks, named Attack on Titan INSIDE

Comment: it sounds like a joke, "machoness" but it is in one attack on titan wikia http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Reiner_Braun#cite_note-g1.262p128-144

Comment: @Pablo These statistics are still from the Guidebooks, Isayama just had a bit of humor added into it.

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler from season 3 episode 10

> The armored titan is found lying defeated in the ground and the beast titan says I won. It would seem the Beast Titan is more powerful than the Armored Titan

Comment: Most of the time the beast titan fights by throwing. If i remember correctly the only time he used hand to hand fighting was against Levi in season 3 part 2 episode 17.